# How to handle a POST request for one to many relationship in Vapor 3.0?

Tags: swift, rest, vapor

Trying to write the request handler for the following request:

POST -> `/properties/{:propertyId}/issues`

The handler should create a new Issue for the Property with `propertyId`.

I've registered the route like so:

```
router.post(Issue.self, at: "properties", Int.parameter, "issues", use: createIssueHandler)
```

How would I write the handler to take `propertyId` from the request parameters, rather than requiring it in the JSON body?

```
func createIssueHandler(_ req: Request, data: Issue) throws -> Future<Issue> {
    let propertyId = try req.parameters.next(Int.self)
    let issue = Issue(
        title: data.title, 
        description: data.description,
        propertyId: propertyId
    )
    return issue.save(on: req)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

credit to @AxelCB from Vapor's Discord chat

if Property conforms to Parameter, you could do:

```
router.post(Issue.self, at: "properties", Property.parameter, "issues", use: createIssueHandler)

func createIssueHandler(_ req: Request, data: Issue) throws -> Future<Issue> {
    try req.parameters.next(Property.self).flatMap(to: Issue.self) { property -> Future<Issue> in
        data.propertyId = property.id
        return issue.save(on: req)
    }
}
```

If what you send in `parameters.next` is a model, and the next parameter is the same type as that model's ID, it will try to find your model with that ID, and throw some error if it's not found